# Solve the following equation for $x$ given $ \log_2(x)=1-(x-2)^2$

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

Solve for $x$ the following equation given : $\log_2(x)=1-(x-2)^2$
I tried to discuss the variation of the function $f(x)=\log_2(x)$ and $g(x)=1-(x-2)^2$  so I found that $x=1$ or $x=2$ but another solution is missing
I tried a lot help please and Thank you

Comment: I strongly suspect it is your homework... Here is **not** do my homework site.

Comment: The other solution needs to be found numerically.

Comment: 0.22548259432667502868...

Comment: Nightflight no it isn't i found this question in a book and i m searching the solution i find 1 and 2

Comment: Kenta S how you find it

Comment: Since you ask, here's [one way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) to find it. [Here's another](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steffensen%27s_method) that spares you doing calculus.

Comment: Does exist a way for terminal student?

Comment: @aminelahmouz: It is now clear from your posting what level you are. Now, as Lulu mentioned in her posting, the other solutions may require numerical methods. If $\phi(x)=1-(2-x)^2-\log_2(x)$, then $\phi(.1)>0$ while $\phi(.5)<0$. Being continuous, $\phi$ must have a root between $.1$ and $.5$. Then you can spit the interval $[.1,.5]$ right in the middle and see in which subinterval $[.1,.3]$ or $[.3,.5]$ there is a change of signed, and continue. You can program this in your favorite computer language to get an approximation the the root.

Comment: Ok thank you but there isn't any method to find the exact value ??

Comment: @Kenta S how did you find it??